# Why is the requests randomly empty when submitting an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-forge

### The Issue

Request being sent via ajax is empty within the controller, results in

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The majority of requests are submitted with no problems and have the data that is expected in the request. The error occurs seemingly *randomly* and we have been unable to reproduce the error even with replicating inputs of a user that receives in errors.

The issue starting occurring after updating Laravel Forge to PHP 7.1 from PHP 7.0. Once we noticed the error we downgraded to PHP 7.0 but the error persisted.

### What we know

- There seems to be no relation between

  - Browser
  - Browser version
  - User input
- Request is submitted via ajax
- There is no data in the request at the top of the controller

### Relevant code where data is being sent via ajax

Simplified form HTML

```
<form>
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <label>Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var signatureImageUrl = $("#jSignature").get(0).toDataURL();

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submit",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: {
        "visit_data": $("form").serializeArray()
    }
});
```

### Relevant code where the error is being thrown within the controller

```
public function submit(Request $request) {
    try {
        foreach ($request->input('visit_data') as $index => $visitComponent) {
            // Iterates over data
        }
    } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
        // Handles error
    }
}
```

### The Question

Why is the request randomly empty when submitting an ajax request?

Comment: Given the question you will need to try to replicate the problem until it occurs and you can glean more information from the browser's developer tools.

Comment: ([Cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/86bsjy/help_php_expert_insight_needed_for_difficult_bug/)).

Answer (score 0):

Without having a view into the client's developer tools/console when the problem occurs it would be nearly impossible to answer the question. There are some things you can do so the user doesn't see some odd error come up on their screen:

`foreach()` expects an array and an empty string is being sent. You should test for emptiness before processing:

```
if(!empty($request->input('visit_data')) {
    foreach ($request->input('visit_data') as $index => $visitComponent) {
        // Iterates over data
    }
}
```

If the AJAX call is sending an empty request you can add an additional check to make sure the variable is set and it isn't empty:

```
if(isset($request->input('visit_data')) && !empty($request->input('visit_data')) {
    foreach ($request->input('visit_data') as $index => $visitComponent) {
        // Iterates over data
    }
}
```

Comment: When a non-empty request is received by the submit method the `$request->input('visit_data')` is iterated over with no issue. You bring up a valid point though it doesn't address the issue being encountered.

Comment: Also, the `foreach()` should never receive an empty string. There is JS validation that is outside of the scope of the issue that prevents the ajax call from firing if the `visit_data` is not populated.

Comment: But you said the AJAX is sending an empty request? So is the variable not there at all @cody?

Comment: We are unsure if it's an error within the JS or PHP but the end result is that the controller receives an empty request, hopefully that helps some to clarify. When the `request` is printed out the it's an empty array.

Comment: Also to quote the original post **The error occurs seemingly randomly and we have been unable to reproduce the error even with replicating inputs of a user that receives in errors.**. The root issue is this

Comment: So, is the question about what causes this to occur randomly? If so, that is not clear in your original post. As a matter of fact, there is no question in your question @cody

Comment: The question is why the error is occurring when it does. What causes the issue is seemingly random so that a a part of the problem. I thought describing the issue got that point across but I understand how it doesn't ask a deliberate question.

Comment: Am I correct to assume the user always tries to submit something, but randomly the request is empty?

Comment: So the question should be, "Why is the request randomly empty when submitting the form?"?

Comment: Something along those lines, I'd say "Why is the request randomly empty when submitting an ajax request?"